# How characters are transmitted over a form?

Tags: php, html, forms, unicode, encoding

```
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-7">
</head>
```

I've been working with forms and see that the `<meta charset="ISO-8859-7">`  tag encode the text that will be typed within a text area. Thing that the encoding method used to store the file isn't does.

I've saw that if a character typed isn't part of the encoding speciefied by the `<meta charset="ISO-8859-7">` tag, the character will be [referenced](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/charset.html#entities) (&#D;)

I was supposing that the form was sending bytes sequences from the encoding speciefied.
Cuz if i type a character whatever it is, will be a byte that an encoding will interpret.

For example with the `<meta charset="ISO-8859-7">`
i type in a form the character `"¥"`

This char isn't part of the encoding but it must send as a byte of the position that it represents `A5`, no matter if it can be represented (This is maked normally by any editor).

But not, the form don't send it as a byte, rather the character is [referenced](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/charset.html#entities).

Code:

**index.php**:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-7'); ?>

<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-7">
</head>
<form method="post" action="encode.php" accept-charset="ISO-8859-7">
    <p><textarea name="input" maxlength="10" rows="5" cols="100"></textarea></p>
    <p><button>Submit</button></p>
</form>
```

**encode.php**:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-7"><!-- Useless, Even if is specified the ISO-8859-1 where the "¥" exist, the form sended a reference char rather an a byte to interpret.-->
</head>
<?php
    $input=$_POST["input"];
    var_dump($input);
?>
```

Result in Sourcecode:

```
string(6) "&#165;"
```

Note: I've tested changing the Encoding used to store the file.

in the **index.php**:
Doesn't matter what encoding is used to store the file, the form always will send accordingly with the `accept-charset=""` attribute or with the `<meta charset="">` tag if the `accept-charset=""` is not specified.

And with the **encode.php**:
The string is never encoded by the file. Can be worked and represented, but the encoding used to store the file has nothing to do with that.

Comment: I use UTF-8 but i was wondering about this issue.

Comment: Could the `Content-Type` header be sending a conflicting character set?

Comment: @cbuck I've added at the beggining `<?php  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-7'); ?>` and still the same.

Comment: And `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the form won't go amiss either.

Comment: @cbuck Added and still the same, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the typed character is not supported by the form encoding.

As far as I can see, neither HTML 4 nor HTML 5 specifies what the browser should do, if the user enters a character in a form field that is not supported by the form encoding.

HTML 5 *does* specify that unsupported characters should be replaced by an ASCII `?` in the query part of URLs¹ (and thus in GET form submissions?), but I can't find anything for POST forms.

It seems that all the browsers (or at least IE, FF, Chrome, Opera) have agreed on encoding unsupported characters as an XML entity. (A better approach would probably have been to warn the user and prevent form submission, but that's water under the bridge.)

The solution is, of course, to use UTF-8 all the way. Then all characters are supported by the encoding, and this problem doesn't arise.

---

¹ [2.6.3 Resolving URLs. *HTML 5, W3C Working Draft 25 May 2011*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/urls.html#resolving-urls), item 8.1:

> If the character in question cannot be expressed in the encoding *encoding*, then replace it with a single 0x3F octet (an ASCII question mark) [...]

Fun fact: The above only applies to the *query* part (the part after the question mark) of the [IRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier). The *path* portion is *always* encoded using UTF-8. And the host name is of course encoded using [Punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode). The mind boggles.

Comment: So there is no way to the form accept a non-part of an encoding character?

Comment: About that HTML5 specify that unsupported chars should be replaced by... Its probably the same as POST method, can u reference that info please?

Comment: 1) Good point, I've added a reference. 2) There is no well-defined way for a form to accept characters that are not supported by the form encoding. (The form encoding can be given explicitly on the <form> tag or derived from the document encoding.)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to also bind the charset to the form-element?

```
<form method="post" action="encode.php" accept-charset="ISO-8859-7">
```

eg. if you use utf-8, you first have to decode the post:

```
$input=utf8_decode($_POST["input"]);
```

not quite sure if this covers your topic, but i hope it helps somehow :)

Comment: Thank you but still same as the above, the point is that the form don't send as a byte, even if i use the `utf8_decode()` function, there is nothing to decode. And about the `accept-charset="ISO-8859-7"` still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The charset references are more about what a browser receives (or accepts in his request header) and not what or how you enter something into a form.

I believe what you type is not relevant to the charset definition in your HTML document. What matters is you keyboard language and how you enter the characters. If you have a keyboard language with a YEN sign your browser will recognize the YEN sign and performs the translation accordingly into either an entity or a character reference. You wanted a YEN sign you will get a YEN and not the greek A5 representation.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the cause of your specific issue, but is something to bear in mind when having character encoding woes: save your PHP scripts using the same character encoding. Doing otherwise can easily cause problems of this sort.

Comment: Yes its principally what i do, but i was corious about the issue. thank man.